# Put number of page in rtf document (ruby on Rails gem)

Tags: ruby, numbers, rubygems, rtf

i have the gem rtf 0.3.0

the documentation is here:

http://ruby-rtf.rubyforge.org/docs/index.html

I already made the footer but i need to know how to get the number of the page.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the ruby-rtf at rubyforge is very old. Check it out at https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf

They say that they have **known issues with header and footer**. I don't know how helpful this was, but I wish you good luck and that you post any solution you find.